# Gmail returns base64 encoded but lists as quotable printable

Tags: gmail-api

When I call the Gmail API I get the following back (just an excerpt obviously since the body is massive:

```
{
  ...
  payload: {
    ...
    parts: [
      {
        "partId": "1",
        "mimeType": "text/html",
        "filename": "",
        "headers": [
         {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\""
         },
         {
          "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
          "value": "quoted-printable"
         }
        ],
        "body": {
             "size": 4696,
             "data": "PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-PGh0bWwgbGFuZz1lbj48....
```

I have just included the relevant parts. You will see that the html body part has the email encoded as base64Url, but toe content transfer encoding clearly says quoted-printable. I run it through a base64url decoder and it gives the correct data. But the header explicitly says it is quoted-printable

What am I missing?

The plain body part is this, which seems perfectly correct.

> ```
> "headers": [
>  ...
> {
>  "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
>  "value": "base64"
> }   ],
> "body": {
>  "size": 601,
>  "data": "R29vZ2xlIEFQSXMgRXhwbG9yZXIgd2FzIGdyYW5
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you request a [Message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages), the `Gmail API` can deliver message data in one of four formats that you can set via a query string ([see documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)).

Below is a description of each format option, taken from the official docs:

> - "**full**": Returns the full email message data with body content parsed    in the **payload** field; the **raw** field is not used.
>   (default)
> - "**metadata**": Returns only email message ID, labels, and email headers.
> - "**minimal**": Returns only email message ID and labels; does not return    the email headers, body, or payload.
> - "**raw**": Returns the full email message data with body content in the    raw field as a base64url encoded string; the payload field is
>   not used.

"**full**" is the default option where the body content is parsed and automatically stored as a base64 encoded string in the data property.

Keep in mind that the Message resource object is provided as a convenience to interact with the [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) payload and it always provides its data payload in `base64` regardless of the value on the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

If you want to wrangle with the raw [IMF(Internet Message Format - RFC5322)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) text, then set the format to "**raw**" in your query string. You'll have to base64 decode the raw string to get the IMF data. It will look exactly as you expect, but you'll have to write your own parser to manage its contents.

Comment: So why is it in one part the content transfer encoding is listed as base64 and in the other as quoted-printable?

Comment: Messages are transmitted as IMF (ie. "**raw**" format) and the html is encoded as quotable printable but it is conveniently converted for you when you fetch a `Message` resource using the GMail API. Rule of thumb, the headers describe the originally transmitted IMF message; the data you get in Gmail's custom data envelope  (ie. in the **`body`** property) automatically transforms that payload to eliminate the tedium of converting it (from quotable printable) yourself.

Comment: Its appears that the Gmail API only does this for quotable-printable encodings.